# Script disabling/enabling foreign keys

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, plsql

I want to script disabling and enabling Foriegn KEY constraints.

I'm testing with the following setup. As you can see from below I am able to successfully disable the constraints but I can't seem to get the enable part to work as it shows no output.

Below is my test CASE with some sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
(CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) AS
SELECT 1, 'Faith', 'Mazzarone' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Lisa', 'Saladino' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Micheal', 'Palmice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Joseph', 'Zaza' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Jerry', 'Torchiano' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);

CREATE TABLE items 
(PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE) AS
SELECT 100, 'Black Shoes', 79.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Brown Pants', 111.99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'White Shirt', 10.99 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE items 
ADD CONSTRAINT items_pk PRIMARY KEY (product_id);

create table purchases(
  ORDER_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
  customer_id   number, 
  PRODUCT_ID NUMBER, 
  QUANTITY NUMBER, 
  purchase_date timestamp
);

ALTER TABLE purchases 
ADD CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT customers_fk FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id);

ALTER TABLE purchases ADD CONSTRAINT items_fk FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES items(product_id);

insert  into purchases (customer_id, product_id, quantity, purchase_date) 
SELECT 3, 102, 4,TIMESTAMP '2022-12-22 21:44:35' + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY') FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 15 UNION ALL 
select 1, 101,3, date '2023-03-29' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 12
union all
select 2, 101,2, date '2023-01-15' + level * interval '8' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 2, 102,2,date '2023-04-13' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select 3, 101,2, date '2023-02-01' + level * interval '1 05:03' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 10
union all
select 3, 101,1, date '2023-04-22' + level * interval '23' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 23
union all
select 3, 100,1,  date '2022-03-01' + level * interval '1 00:23:05' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
select 4, 102,1, date '2023-01-01' + level * interval '5' hour from dual
          connect by level <= 60;

BEGIN
    FOR c IN
    (SELECT c.owner,c.table_name,c.constraint_name
    FROM user_constraints c,user_tables t
    WHERE c.table_name=t.table_name
    AND c.status='ENABLED'
    ORDER BY c.constraint_type DESC,c.last_change DESC
    )
    LOOP
        FOR D IN
        (SELECT P.Table_Name Parent_Table,C1.Table_Name Child_Table,C1.Owner,P.Constraint_Name Parent_Constraint,
            c1.constraint_name Child_Constraint
        FROM user_constraints p
        JOIN user_constraints c1 ON(p.constraint_name=c1.r_constraint_name)
        WHERE(p.constraint_type='P'
        OR p.constraint_type='U')
        AND c1.constraint_type='R'
        AND p.table_name=UPPER(c.table_name)
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(' Disable the constraint ' || d.Child_Constraint ||' (on table '||d.owner || '.' ||
            d.Child_Table || ')') ;
            dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement('alter table ' || d.owner || '.' ||d.Child_Table || ' disable constraint ' ||
            d.Child_Constraint) ;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/

Statement processed.
Disable the constraint ITEMS_FK (on table XXX.PURCHASES). 

Disable the constraint CUSTOMERS_FK (on table XXX.PURCHASES).

/* no output GENERATED*/

BEGIN
    FOR c IN
    (SELECT c.owner,c.table_name,c.constraint_name
    FROM user_constraints c,user_tables t
    WHERE c.table_name=t.table_name
    AND c.status='DISABLED'
    ORDER BY c.constraint_type DESC,c.last_change DESC
    )
    LOOP
        FOR D IN
        (SELECT P.Table_Name Parent_Table,C1.Table_Name Child_Table,C1.Owner,P.Constraint_Name Parent_Constraint,
            c1.constraint_name Child_Constraint
        FROM user_constraints p
        JOIN user_constraints c1 ON(p.constraint_name=c1.r_constraint_name)
        WHERE(p.constraint_type='P'
        OR p.constraint_type='U')
        AND c1.constraint_type='R'
        AND p.table_name=UPPER(c.table_name)
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(' Enable the constraint ' || d.Child_Constraint ||' (on table '||d.owner || '.' ||
            d.Child_Table || ')') ;
            dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement('alter table ' || d.owner || '.' ||d.Child_Table || ' enable constraint ' ||
            d.Child_Constraint) ;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is the reason for this? You may use `DEFERRABLE` constraints which could be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enabling the constraints, you shouldn't need to use the nested loops.

```
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
        SELECT '"' || a.owner
                    || '"."'
                    || a.table_name
                    || '"' AS full_table_name,
                a.constraint_name
            FROM user_constraints a
            JOIN user_constraints b
                ON ( a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                    AND a.r_owner = b.owner )
            WHERE a.constraint_type = 'R'
                AND b.status = 'DISABLED'
            ORDER BY 1 )  LOOP
            
        dbms_output.put_line ( 'Enable the constraint ' || r.constraint_name ||' (on table ' || r.full_table_name || ')' ) ;
        dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement ( 'alter table ' || r.full_table_name || ' enable constraint ' || r.constraint_name ) ;
        
    END LOOP ;
END ;
/
```

Comment: Can this solution be modified to handle both enable and disable by passing in an a parameter. One piece of code would be preferable

Comment: @Pugzly No reason it couldn't use a parameter to toggle between enabling and disabling the FK constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the code you use for enabling the constraints should be something like below.

Things to improve in your original code:

1. Outer loop selects constraint names, but you use only the table_name
   in the inner loop, because of this the inner loop is repeated for
   every constraint on a table from the outer loop.
2. Inner loop uses `p.table_name=UPPER(c.table_name)` but should be
   `c1.table_name=UPPER(c.table_name)`, because outer loop fetches the
   child tables with disabled FK constraints.

This is just the minimum change I did to make this work for this specific example:

```
BEGIN
    FOR c IN
    (SELECT distinct c.owner,c.table_name--,c.constraint_name
    FROM user_constraints c,user_tables t
    WHERE c.table_name=t.table_name
    AND c.status='DISABLED'
    --ORDER BY c.constraint_type DESC,c.last_change DESC
    )
    LOOP
        FOR D IN
        (SELECT P.Table_Name Parent_Table,C1.Table_Name Child_Table,C1.Owner,P.Constraint_Name Parent_Constraint,
            c1.constraint_name Child_Constraint
        FROM user_constraints p
        JOIN user_constraints c1 ON(p.constraint_name=c1.r_constraint_name)
        WHERE(p.constraint_type='P'
        OR p.constraint_type='U')
        AND c1.constraint_type='R'
        --AND p.table_name=UPPER(c.table_name)
        AND c1.table_name=UPPER(c.table_name)
        )
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(' Enable the constraint ' || d.Child_Constraint ||' (on table '||d.owner || '.' ||
            d.Child_Table || ')') ;
            dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement('alter table ' || d.owner || '.' ||d.Child_Table || ' enable constraint ' ||
            d.Child_Constraint) ;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for your help and expertise